# How can I initialize a default value of QComboBox without to click it?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I initialize a default value of QComboBox without to click it?  I tried with

```
ui->combBox->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

but when I read the value at first I get unfortunately a **-1** and only after the QComboBox was clicked its value become **1**.

Comment: Does the combobox have at least 2 items when you try to set the index to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The `ui->combBox->setCurrentIndex(1);` was in constructor before 
`connect(ui->combBox,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int))`.... 
*@Nikos C.* thank you very much for a good tip.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure there's at least two values in the QComboBox? Counting begins from 0, not 1. If you want to select the first value, you need to:

```
ui->combBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

If that's not the problem, and you indeed have two values in the combo box, then make sure that the ui has been set up first. This call needs to execute first:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
```

It's what actually fills the combo box with the values specified in the .ui file.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The values: true(1) and false(0) were defined in MainWindow.ui file. And then in constructor I try to set value ui->combBox->setCurrentIndex(1);

Comment: I can set the value in the MainWindow to true(1) or false(0) it works correct, but if read the value of the QComboBox before to click it, I get a **-1** :((

Comment: Are you trying to select index 1 before the ui has been setup, perhaps? That is, before the `ui->setupUi(this);` call in the constructor?

Comment: But I've just looked it. It's not the problem: at first I call **ui->setupUi(this);** and then **ui->combBox->setCurrentIndex(0);** :(( It's so fare correct.

Comment: Make sure you don't call `ui->setupUi(this)` again later. Qt writes that call automatically when you create the .ui and .cpp files. You could also post the code of the constructor in your question, so that we can verify this.

Comment: **@Nikos Chantziaras** "Make sure you don't call ui->setupUi(this) again later."
I'm sure. That's not problem.. also my question stay up to date :((

Comment: Still, you might want to post the constructor in your question. Maybe then someone can spot what's wrong.